# How can I classify a person by identification of shape?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a program which detect a moving object and I want to classify these objects by identifying the shape of each one with a dataset of shapes.Can any one have any idea how to compare the shape of each object with the dataset using some points of the current shape and compare it with the samples?
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnc85.jpg) 
[detected object1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z6z7.jpg)

Comment: You should do some research before asking the question. There's plenty of material in shape/people recognition on the internet.

Comment: @sammy:if I found anything on the net I don't ask my question here.

Comment: post some sample shape classes and sample input images to give an idea of your data.

Comment: try chamfer matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the theory point of view you should start off reading two papers

1) HOG detectors by [Dalal and Trigs](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf)

2) Chamfer Detectors by [Gavrila](http://www.gavrila.net/Research/Chamfer_System/chamfer_system.html)

If you just want to use the edge information, Chamfer is the solution. From my experience it fails miserably on cluttered scenes. HOG produces far superior results.

OpenCV already has human body detector [implemented](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html)

If you are looking for a Machine Learning adventure why not train your own HOG detector using [OpenCV train_cascade](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)? It is very fast and real time

Comment: I tried HOG and SVM but it fails I can't detect persons.

Comment: It doesn't always work right out of the box. Sometimes you have to play around with the parameters. Usually the problem is in getting the minSize and MaxSize parameters correct.

Comment: if I change in the parameters of HOG descriptor,does this resolve the problem?

Comment: Well yes. Sometimes your detector is perfect. The problem is either a too strict requirement for minimum neighbors or searching on the incorrect scale. I admit it is hard to to check. What you could do is use [RunAt](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-runat) on an example you know has a person. Downsize to 130x66 first. Also what dimensions are you looking for person? Upper body? Full Body? The size you will need for upper body is 64x64 and for full body 128x64.

Comment: Sometimes in the image I used the size of a person is less than 128x64.what can I do for that?I'm looking for a full body.

Comment: You can use resize function to increase their size. If they are too small maybe hog is not the right approach for you. Generally HOG requires some minimal resolution to learn the surrounding features